# Convert from GDI32.HDC to awt.Graphics

Tags: java, gdi, jna

I've read a few docs and examples, but I just don't get it.  Is it impossible to convert from `HDC` to `awt.Graphics`?

I know there are already answers that solve this, but they are all very specific. I want to eventually draw to the screen and manipulate the saved image. I think the best way to do this is convert between `BufferedImage` and `HDC` because drawing is very simple using `awt`.

I've just learned about `JNA` so this is probably a very stupid question. It probably doesn't help that I've never worked with C or C++. Anyway, I'm stuck here:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GDI32 GDI = GDI32.INSTANCE;
    User32 user32 = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
    HWND win = user32.GetForegroundWindow();
    HDC winDC = user32.GetDC(win);
    HBITMAP bi = GDI.CreateCompatibleBitmap(winDC, 1024, 1024); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for a compatible bitmap is an array of integer values, although you may have to directly read pixel values from one format and write to the target.  JNA does a transfer of pixels from Java Graphics-generated image to windows HDC in [WindowUtils.java](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/WindowUtils.java#L679).

As for converting something windows has drawn into a `BufferedImage`, you would need to extract the Windows image as pixels and then write those into the `BufferedImage`.